# OOP principles - how to structure classes

Tags: php, oop

I currently have a class `Message_Repository` that has methods like:

```
getLocationDetailsByID($messageId),
getCustomerDetailsById($messageId),
getMessages(),
updateMessageForEmail(array $data), //this takes an array which includes the message ID
getLinkIndicatorById($messageId),
setIndicator($data) //this takes an array which includes the message ID
```

These methods are all database interactions where in most cases I'm selecting various data, and in some cases I'm making updates.

I'm finding as I'm fleshing this out that the name of my class no longer represents what's going on in the class, at least not exclusively.

Is it best practice to have say, a `Location_Repository` class and a `Customer_Repository` class that would house the methods for getting data associated with the subject matter?

Still trying to understand single responsibility. In theory it seems simple enough, but in practice I'm finding that it's more challenging, particularly as my classes are growing and changing. Definitely need to refactor, but want to make sure I'm thinking about this correctly.

**EDIT**
I may have added confusion with the name of my class. It's not a "repository" in the strict sense of design patterns, but merely a naming convention for the class I'm using to interact with the database. Probably need to rename it.

Comment: Can you give a quick outline of what these functions do? What ID are you passing to those functions? Is it a Message ID, or the Location/Customer/LinkIndicator ID?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the message ID is the main key between the various tables in the database, and most of the methods are using that message ID to get to the needed data, so it's passed into all of the methods I mentioned. There are one or 2 other methods (not listed in my question) that don't take the message ID.

Comment: I see. In that case, your constructor should take the ID, then you should have `getLocationDetails` as a non-static method on the object, which will return those details.

Comment: So the only problem there is that the getMessages() method gets called right after instantiating the object and when called, returns a bunch of information including the message ID which is subsequently used later in the main script to call the other methods. So I guess I would need to call the getMessages() method from the constructor and  set $this->message_id = $message_id returned from getMessages()?

Comment: Sounds like you might be better off with either a static `Message_Repository::getMessages()` method, *or* have `Message_Repository` have as its sole responsibility `getMessages`, and have a separate `Message` class representing a single message. I think the second might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Single responsability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is an OOP concept to atomization, which leads towards [Encapsulation concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Those concepts are bounded together by the [SOLID Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), a strong principle that will save a lot of your time and avoids headaches for the rest of your life:

> Single responsibility principle: a class should have only a single
>   responsibility (i.e. only one potential change in the software's
>   specification should be able to affect the specification of the class)
>
> Open/closed principle “software entities … should be open for
>   extension, but closed for modification.”
>
> Liskov substitution principle “objects in a program should be
>   replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the
>   correctness of that program.” See also design by contract.
>
> Interface segregation principle “many client-specific interfaces are
>   better than one general-purpose interface.”
>
> Dependency inversion principle one should “depend upon abstractions,
>   [not] concretions.”

Without understand all your business rules and read your code carefully, it's difficult to analyze how you should organize your software, but I'll give a shot:

MessageRepository don't extends Customer or Location, but are [compounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) by them.

[image: Composition Example]
In the image above, an example of Composition toke from the Wikipedia

In your construct from MessageRepository you will instance those classes to use as you want inside MessageRepository. The perfect situation is avoid have public variables in the class and rely profoundly in the methods to retrieve and set Data (I looked you already did something in that way). So, as far I can understand by methods name:

MessageRepository methods:

- public getMessages();
- public updateMessageForEmail(array $data); //this takes an array which includes the message ID
- public getLinkIndicatorById($messageId);
- public setIndicator($data); //this takes an array which includes the message ID

LocationRepository methods:

- public getLocationDetailsByID($messageId);

CustomerRepository methods:

- public getCustomerDetailsById($messageId);

It's important to remember: your business rules methods should be private.

Suggestions to readability:

- Avoid underlines into class names;
- Avoid repeat the class name or bus. rule into method. I.E. getLocationDetailsByID should be getById(), always remember - your methods will have instances, so would be called: $this->location->getById(). The same applies to all your methods described.

About naming, It's a GREAT question about that. I suggest you study Design Patterns/Software Architectures, my favorite one ([opposing Uncle Bob perspective](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884)) is MVC ([Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) architecture:

[image: MVC Schema]

Your 'Repositories' which have Business Rules principles and Database abstraction should be an Model, so, if you want to use that Pattern, create MVC dir structure and works towards it!

Comment: great points on readability. Any thoughts on naming? If I had a class Location_Repository, should that just be Location? Do I need to differentiate it in the name as being something that accesses the DB, or is that unnecessary?  naming things is hard.

Comment: I'll put on my answer, hold on

Comment: IMHO, that UncleBob's lecture is less about MVC  and more about "how Rails is not doing MVC".

Comment: @tereško Yeah, but in several of his presentations he doesn't talk very well about MVC in some way or another, so I decided to put here just to show a material talking something different than me (and a good reference to OP study other correlated things :)

Answer (score 2):

A repository should only be managing entities or [domain objects](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject), that are instance of the same class. In your particular case, you should be splitting in at least three separate repository for `Message` instance, for `Location` instances and for `Client` instance. And probably a third repository for whatever "link indicators" are.

Also, the repository class is [not were your SQL code goes](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

As for SRP, the best description of what makes the code adhere to it is: *"when class has only has one reason to change"*.

If you look at the Fowler's article, you will notice, that are repository actually interacts with multiple dependencies of it's own. And the SQL should probably go in one or more [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

Comment: that's good info about the repository class. I think for me this was just a name rather than a concrete design pattern as I'm not that experienced with OOP as of yet. This is essentially a data access class. Any pattern or naming convention recommendations for that?

Comment: Repository is not really as "data access class". I would say that it is an abstraction, they you would put around code, that begins to require logic, when choosing which data mapper to use for interaction with persistence. That's when you make a repository to isolate that part of logic. Lemmes see if I can dig up an example of code, where that would be useful.

Comment: @hyphenas an example, most of the logic in [this method](https://github.com/glome/cbc/blob/overhaul/src/cashback/Model/Services/Recognition.php#L19) should actually be moved in a repository (just don't use that codebase for learning, it's bad), because it would let you abstract all the "fiddling" with "which mapper to pick".

Comment: @hyphen as for "naming convention", there are two things to know. **First:**  never use patterns as recipes. They are "shorthand descriptions", that developers use to describe the general idea of the code (either for what has been written or what they are about to write). It's a statement of intent. **Second:** it looks like what you wrote is closer to combination of multiple data mappers (or maybe table data gateways).

Comment: And one more thing, since php [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), you can avoid using the "Repository" suffix and instead put in a namespace of same name.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd split them up, so you would have a Repository for each model type. For example all methods that return a 'Location' model should be in the 'Location' Repository. Similarly with Update methods, which would be passed a 'Location' model to update.

Comment: they are not "models"

Answer (score 1):

If we go with Doctrine repositories as a standard, then pretty much yes, you would have a repository for every data type.

```
Message_Repository::getLocationDetailsByID();
```

Would probably become:

```
Location_Repository::getLocationDetailsByMessageID();
```

Single responsibility here is adhered to by each repository fetching data relevant to their own data type.

In Doctrine, this is somewhat implied by EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder() preloading the builder with a `->select(/* own data type */)`.

But every repository is different, you can group data types into "concepts" and handle them in the same place while still adhering to SRP, but as your application grows, its best to split them up.